# regex doesn't do what I think I tell it to do

Tags: python, regex

I have this string:
    FW:MKEQP2B4.BIN

I need to seperate the part after FW: from the rest of it. Since this is just a part of a bigger string and for different string the FW: can be formatted differently I decided to use regex.

I have this regex `FW:.*(\S+).*` but it matches my string but `.group(1)` is just a single character 'N'. I use `.search()`

Why does regex behave so odd for such a seemingly easy task...

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect; regex *does* do what you tell it to. What you call "odd behavior" is, in fact, [documented](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and [discussed on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

Comment: If you'll always have an 8.3 filename at the end of the string, just use `my_str[-12:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex does exactly what you are telling it to do. Its just that you are not putting it right .

I guess you are looking for :

```
FW:.*?(\S+).*?
```

the lazy one !

infact you dont even need the `.*?`

with `FW:(\S+)`, the result in $1 will be `MKEQP2B4.BIN`

Comment: thx, the regex engine I used up to now didn`t need the `?`. I also do need the space check since this is human input and the space can be there

Comment: Mmm not sure this is very ethical aelor... I normally support your work, but I saw how your solution gradually morphed into mine.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
match = re.search(r"FW:(\S+)", subject)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
else:
    result = ""
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/45), see Group 1 in the right pane.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex to get the string after `FW:`,

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'FW:MKEQP2B4.BIN'
>>> m = re.search(r'(?<=FW:).*', str)
>>> m.group()
'MKEQP2B4.BIN'
```

If you don't want the `.BIN` part then try this,

```
>>> m = re.search(r'(?<=FW:).*?(?=\.)', str)
>>> m.group()
'MKEQP2B4'
```